# Find elements from an array whose sum equals a given number

Tags: c, recursion, functional-programming, sum

I am try to write a A recursive implementation, but it dont work. Can you help me to find mistake. I need just a recursive solution on C.

```
 void findsum(int arr[],int i, int k){
    if (k <= 0 || arr[i] > k) return;
    if (arr[i] <= k) {
        k -= arr[i];
        if (k == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Summ %d, %d",arr[i], arr[i]); return;
        }
    }
    if (i == (25)) return;

    for (int a=i ;a<25; a ++ ) {
        findsum(arr, a, k);
    }
}
int main()
{
  int set[] = {18897109, 12828837, 9461105, 6371773, 5965343, 5946800, 5582170, 5564635, 5268860, 4552402, 4335391, 4296250, 4224851, 4192887, 3439809, 3279833, 3095313, 2812896, 2783243, 2710489, 2543482, 2356285, 2226009, 2149127, 2142508, 2134411};
   int sum = 100000000;
 int n = sizeof(set)/sizeof(set[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        findsum(set, i, sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `but it dont work. Can you help me to find mistake.` what is not work? Where is mistak?

Comment: function findsum dont stop

Comment: Also you every time initialize `i = 0` by `for (i = 0 ;i<26; i ++ )`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding number of subsets of an array that add up to a multiple of a specific number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945109/finding-number-of-subsets-of-an-array-that-add-up-to-a-multiple-of-a-specific-nu)

Answer (score 0):

You code not stop because every time you assign `i=0` by loop

```
for (i = 0 ;i<26; i ++ ) {
        findsum(arr, i, k);
    }
```

In `findsum` function.

So as per my suggestion you can make some changes as like

first in main

```
int main()
{
    int set[] = {18897109, 12828837, 9461105, 6371773, 5965343, 5946800, 5582170, 5564635, 5268860, 4552402, 4335391, 4296250, 4224851, 4192887, 3439809, 3279833, 3095313, 2812896, 2783243, 2710489, 2543482, 2356285, 2226009, 2149127, 2142508, 2134411};
    int sum = 100000000,i;
    int n = sizeof(set)/sizeof(set[0]);
    findsum(set, n, sum);
}
```

And second in `findsum` like

```
void findsum(int arr[],int i, int k)
{

    if (k <= 0 || arr[i] > k) return;

    if (arr[i] <= k) 
    {
        k -= arr[i];
        if (k == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Summ %d, %d",arr[i], arr[i]); return;
        }
    }

    if (i == 25) return;

    findsum(arr, i, k);
}
```